# ng-repeat with anonymous function that is in a $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate my html tables that navigates through nav-menu. My tables create with `ng-repeat`. Here is my `.js` file

```
carApp.controller("OtherCarTablesCtrl", function($scope, getAllCars){
    $scope.tabArray = [2,3,4]
    $scope.carList = []

    function sortCars(index){
        getAllCars.get().success(function(data){
            var CarList = [];
            ....
            return CarList;
        });
    }

    $scope.switchCarList = function(index){
        switch (index-1) {
            case 1:
                $scope.carList = sortCars(1);
                console.log("case 1 was passed");
                return $scope.carList;
            case 2:
                $scope.carList = sortCars(2);
                console.log("case 2 was passed");
                return $scope.carList;
            case 3:
                $scope.carList = sortCars(3);
                console.log("case 3 was passed");
                return $scope.carList;
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the part of my html file:

```
<div ng-controller="OtherCarTablesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabArray">
        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected({{tab}})">
            ....
            <tbody ng-repeat="car in switchCarList(tab)">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run my app in a browser and open the console I see that `"case 1 was passed"`,`"case 2 was passed"` and `"case 3 was passed"` are printing out all the time without stop.

Why is that happening? How can I fix that?

Comment: You can share your full code for complete testing..

Comment: the other parts are not depend on the question

Comment: this code is all you need top execute and test my issue

Comment: You have 3 tabs and one car list for each tab, so I'm not quite sure what you expect.

Comment: yeah, if you looked at my `.js` file you would see that i made a switch statement that modifies carl list

Comment: do you want to generate multiple table depends on number of tabArray element. is it?

Answer (score -1):

Add break in your switch cases

Comment: But the code is working right. You have used loop so it will go in all the conditions what wrong there?

Comment: I am using `break` statement in my code but I didn't mention it here.

Answer (score -1):

`<div ng-repeat="tab in tabArray">` here tabArray is `[2,3,4]` so for each tab like (2,3,4) `<tbody ng-repeat="car in switchCarList(tab)">` will execute one time.

when `tab=2` `$scope.switchCarList(tab)` is called so index inside switch become equal to tab that is 2.
so `switch (index-1)` is equal to switch(1) and case 1 will execute.

when `tab=3` `$scope.switchCarList(tab)` is called so index inside switch become equal to tab that is 3.
so `switch (index-1)` is equal to switch(2) and case 2 will execute.

when `tab=4` `$scope.switchCarList(tab)` is called so index inside switch become equal to tab that is 4.
so `switch (index-1)` is equal to switch(3) and case 1 will execute.

thats all. if you dont want to execute all this cases. then remove  `<div ng-repeat="tab in tabArray">`